# javascript change background by time of the day

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following script that change images by time of the day, but its possible to change and other CSS like background or text color together with image?

Thanks you for any help!

```
var imgs = [
            'http://myurl.com/1.jpg', 
            'http://myurl.com/2.jpg', 
            'http://myurl.com/3.jpg', 
            'http://myurl.com/4.jpg'
            ]; 
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#img').ImageResize({ origImageWidth: "924" });
            var now = new Date();
            var HH = now.getHours();
            if ((HH >= 6) && (HH < 10)) {
            document.getElementById('img').src = imgs[0];
            } else if ((HH >= 10) && (HH < 20)) {
            document.getElementById('img').src = imgs[1];
            } else if ((HH >= 20) && (HH < 24)){
            document.getElementById('img').src = imgs[2];
            } else {
            document.getElementById('img').src = imgs[3];
            }
            });


<img id="img" src="" alt="">
```

Comment: yes,, you can also do that, just store 4 colors in an array, and change color on above condition.

Comment: yes ..you can use with [`Dom css`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question , yes you can do that. But I would recommend to make classes for each hour of day and change that with time. For e.g.

css :

```
.theme-morning {background-color: red; text-color: yellow;}
.theme-evening {background-color: green; text-color: white;}
.theme-night {background-color: blue; text-color: yellow;}
.theme-latenight {background-color: black; text-color: green;}
```

javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#img').ImageResize({ origImageWidth: "924" });
    var now = new Date();
    var HH = now.getHours();
    var selectedImg;
    var theme;
    if ((HH >= 6) && (HH < 10)) {
        selectedImg = imgs[0];
        theme = 'theme-morning';
    } else if ((HH >= 10) && (HH < 20)) {
        selectedImg = imgs[1];
        theme = 'theme-evening';
    } else if ((HH >= 20) && (HH < 24)){
        selectedImg = imgs[2];
        theme = 'theme-night';
    } else {
        selectedImg = imgs[3];
        theme = 'theme-latenight';
    }
    $('#img').attr('src', selectedImg);
    $('body').attr('class', theme);
});
```

Comment: Please upvote the answer if you found this useful !! :P